# A graph with exactly 5 different topological sortings of vertices

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I am struggling to find a graph with exactly 5 different topological sortings of vertices. It's always either too much or too many. Could you help me find such graph? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean DAG?

$$a\to b\to c\to d\to e\leftarrow f$$

You can put $f$ on any position before $e$. There are $5$ possibilities.

Comment: DAG=Directed Acyclic Graph